# AFCI breaker trouble?

Tags: electrical

I have installed 3 AFCI breakers, and every one trips under instantaneous load. I cleaned up all the wiring in all the boxes as best I could, and checked for cut/bare wires. I replaced all the breakers with standard breakers, and everything works perfectly. What gives?

Comment: Are you connecting the identified conductors properly?  The identified conductors (neutrals) for each circuit also need to be tied into the respective breaker, and the pigtail for the breaker tied to the neutral bar.

What loads are on the circuit?  Light and plugs, plugs only, appliances?

Comment: Yeah, the breaker is installed correctly. The three circuits are for the lighting and receptacles in three bedrooms. No more then 10 outlets on each circuit. As soon as I flip the light switch in any of the bedrooms- click.

Comment: What make and model are the AFCIs?

Comment: What exactly does the light switch turn on?

Comment: Square D. They turn on the overhead lights- one bedroom circuit has one incandescent, the second bedroom circuit has an LED can light and an incandescent fixture, the master circuit has a two-bulb incandescent and the master closet (master circuit) has three LED cans.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel sorry, Square D type HOM115CAFI Issue No. DP-3640

Comment: There is a four-digit date code stamped on the front of your breaker then -- is it greater than 1130?

Comment: Are you 100% sure each circuit's neutral goes to the same breaker as its hot?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel- 1506 is stamped right next to the switch.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz- I'm glad you asked. I think I did overlook the fact that the circuit's ground needs to be connected to the breaker itself; I connected them, along with the breakers' pigtails, to the neutral bar. I should have read Connor's comment more carefully! Thanks, y'all! Side note: I think it's a bit weird that the inspector didn't notice my mistake...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### AFCIs trip on ground faults too

Most AFCI breakers require the circuit neutral to be connected to the *breaker* like a GFCI breaker, not to the panelboard neutral bar.  This is done so that the AFCI can correctly detect certain classes of faults (such as a neutral to ground arc), but also gives them properties similar to a GFCI in that they will trip on the same wiring errors that trip GFCIs (such as improperly wired or shared neutrals), and will do so as soon as load is applied in the case of an errant neutral wire.   Fixing the neutral wiring will make them happy again.